# What is a How (placename)?

Tags: etymology, toponyms

In a 1907 translation of Icelandic mythology I came across a reference to a place called "Svarin's How". This reminded me of Aslan's How in the Narnia books, a specific place name for a sort of hollowed out hill.

What is a How? It seems to be an archaic word. I've only come across it in these two places - are there any other places that talk about a How?

Comment: There is a place called *Carlinghow* in West Yorkshire and another called *Carlin How* near Redcar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Wordsense](https://www.wordsense.eu/haugr/) gives the etymology from Old Norse *haugr*

> Akin to hár ("high"), Danish høj‎ ("hill"), Northern Sami hög‎
> ("hill"), North English how.
>
> Noun haugr (masc.) (genitive haugs, plural haugar) howe, mound; dung
> heap, midden cairn; sacrificial mound

> how (pl. hows) (dialectal) An artificial barrow or tumulus.
> (dialectal) A small hill in northern England. (Usage preserved mainly
> in place names.)

The family name Howe has at its origins someone who lived near a hill.

These hows are not derived from how as in manner or *way,* but it should go without saying that C.S. Lewis was a wordsmith and philosopher.

Comment: But on the How, did Horton hear a Who?

Comment: _OED_ adds that it is apparently related to Old Germanic *hauh-* high.

Answer (score 3):

The Compact OED (paywalled online, I don't subscribe) has a definition for *how* as "a hill, hillock", restricted in occurrence to northern England.

The etymology is completely different from *how*, the way of doing something.